# Fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups query

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Just had a question about how to apply this theorem.

If I am only told that a group is of finite order and is Abelian can we use this theorem? Is there a way to ensure it is finitely generated, or do we need more information. If not, what are the applications of this theorem?

Further, when the order of the group is finite and told to us, e.g. 800, how can we use this theorem to find the isomorphism types? Because 800 is not equal to $p^n$ for some prime. Are we expected to split this into $2^5*5^2$ (since 32 and 25 are coprime) and then apply the theorem onto each of these?
If so, why doesn't the theorem state that we need to do this first, or stipulate that the order of the group is a power of a prime?

Thanks

Comment: Note: Any finite group is finitely generated by all its finitely many elements.

Comment: If a group has finite order, since order is just the number of elements it has, then obviously it is finitely generated.

Comment: Noted, thanks. So suppose we had a group with a finite order equal to $p_1^n * p_2^n$ how would we apply this theorem? I can't see how we can ensure that $d_1 | d_2 | d_3$ . . .

Comment: there are two abelian groups of order $p^2$ but there is only one (abelian) group of order $pq$, the Sylow theorems give more details ?

Comment: For this course we don't use Sylow's theorems. How would one approach the above question using only the fundamental theorem above? I.e. how would we decompose this group of order $p_1^n p_2^m$, in terms of isomorphism types.

Comment: the Sylow 1st or 0th theorem : find the elements with order $p^k$, and pick one with maximum $k$, and remove the generated cyclic subgroup by quotienting

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear I would like an explanation that directly uses the fundamental theorem of finitely generated Abelian groups, as opposed to general group theory.

That is, if we had a group that is not a power of a prime, how can we directly use the fundamental theorem. All the examples I have seen use a power of a prime e.g. a group of order 16 perhaps isormophic to $\mathbb{4} \times \mathbb{4}$ which makes sense to me, but I can not see how you would use it otherwise.